# Choose type while merging pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas

```
/data/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/reshpae/merge.py:963: UserWarning: You are merging on int and float columns where the float values are not equal to their int representation 'representation', UserWarning)
```

I was merging multiple dataframes and got the above message. I was able to find out which columns have different dtypes and changed one. This time, there were only two columns, but I can't deal with this kind of situation every time. (Sometimes, I get more than 10 tables with more than 20 columns each!)

How can I `pd.merge()` while choosing dtypes when they are conflicted? (Obviously, I should go through the data and give a little touch before merging right away. Just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do things.)

Comment: I think they are fixing this type of issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20998

Comment: If you are reading your data from a file you can specify the dtype of your columns